# please help .how to get rid of this error in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

**db.products.insertOne({_id: 1, name: "pen", price: 1.20})**
*bash: syntax error near unexpected token `{_id:'*

Comment: you don't need to add `_id` since it will be created automatically by mongodb I think.

Comment: Which programming language are you using? It looks like it should be `"_id"` instead of just `_id`.

Comment: How are you running this?

Comment: You forgot to run the __mongo-shell__ first! First run the `mongo` command in the terminal then run your query!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The key piece of information in that error message is `bash:`.

This implies that command was execute in a bash shell instead of a mongo shell.

The solution would be to start a mongo shell and connect to the database before running that command.

Answer (score 0):

You can use on compass>

```
db.products.insertOne({_id: 1, name: "pen", price: 1.20})
```

[image]